# D3, Typescript, and GraphNodes (Optional fields in a typescript interface)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, d3.js, typescript, typing

Here are the definitions for `D3.Layout.GraphNode` and `D3.Layout.GraphLink` as defined in [borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

```
export interface GraphNode {
        id: number;
        index: number;
        name: string;
        px: number;
        py: number;
        size: number;
        weight: number;
        x: number;
        y: number;
        subindex: number;
        startAngle: number;
        endAngle: number;
        value: number;
        fixed: bool;
        children: GraphNode[];
        _children: GraphNode[];
        parent: GraphNode;
        depth: number;
    }


    export interface GraphLink {
        source: GraphNode;
        target: GraphNode;
    }
```

However, a `GraphNode` does not necessary always have ALL of these properties. For example, here is a `GraphLink` with a `source:GraphNode` and a `target:GraphNode` , both of which do not have all of the properties.

[image: D3.Layout.GraphNode which does not have all the fields defined]

Furthermore, I can't have a class such as:

```
class GraphData {
    nodes: D3.Layout.GraphNode[];
    links: D3.Layout.GraphLink[];
}
```

Because then doing this does not work:

```
var data:GraphData = {
    "nodes": [{
        "group": 0,
        "id": 0
    }, {
        "group": 0,
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "group": 0,
        "id": 2
    }],
    "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 0,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1
    }]
}
```

The typescript compiler gives me this error:

```
Compile Error. 
See error list for details
 C:/Projects/MyGraph/app.ts(111,23): error TS2082: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:

Types of property 'nodes' of types '{ "nodes": { "group": number; "id": number; }[]; "links": { "source": number; "target": number; "value": number; }[]; }' and 'GraphData' are incompatible:

Type '{ "group": number; "id": number; }' is missing property 'index' from type 'D3.Layout.GraphNode'.
```

A way to fix this is to make all of the fields in the interface `GraphNode` optional. But then the interface is useless.
How do I take advantage of TypeScripts static typing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are not *required* but *perhaps* some are and the interface definition does not reflect that as of yet. Perhaps you can mark which ones are optional for community support.

In any case. When you want to enforce strict behavior on others but want the flexibility to break out your self you can use any. e.g. :

```
var data:GraphData = <any>{
    "nodes": [{
        "group": 0,
        "id": 0
    }, {
        "group": 0,
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "group": 0,
        "id": 2
    }],
    "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 0,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the <any>. About the interface definition: it does not seem that any of the fields are actually required. As you can see in this gist: https://gist.github.com/ldub/5950248 , the d3 engine even auto-generates the `id` field in order for the `source` and `target` properties of the `links` to work properly. I considered marking the optional fields as optional and opening a merge request to DefinitelyTyped, but its hard to tell which of them are optional!

Comment: @LevDubinets that is how life was before typescript :)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, but in this case it seems that typescript doesn't solve the problem that it was created to solve.

Comment: it does for your own code. Its third party js that is painful

Comment: Of course, it is priceless for my own code! But how often do we write javascript that doesn't use third party libraries?